# Power of Ethernet (POE) max distance

Tags: arduino

I know this is not the right place to post and I truly apologize. If someone can send me in the right direction I would really appreciate it or maybe help me. I want to run POE over a distance of between 1 kilometer to 12 kilometer (I know this is very long). Would POE work for me or am I wasting my time researching this. What I want to do is have a single power and communication point to connect Arduino's every 100 meter on a single cable (CAT5 or similar) and communicate over I2C to a single master Arduino unit. I am stuck at this. Thanks again for hearing me out, pointing me in the right direction or answering my question for me. And sorry for my horrible english :-)

Comment: why not use an Arduino with an Ethernet Shield and create a local network over Ethernet, assigning each Arduino an IP (designed for longer distances from the get go) ?

Comment: That is not addressing the problem at all. It is a 12 km long network in a mine. You need to deliver power to all arduinos (but there are no AC power outlets at each corner) and make them communicate (with Ethernet, they would need direct cable runs to an Ethernet switch, which is a horrible length of cabling. Besides max Ethernet segment length is about 100 meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a dedicated Arduino forum, https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ which you may prefer.

Arduino uno draws around 45 mA. Cat5e is 0.188ohm/meter, so the cable has a resistance of 376 ohm (one kilometer power, one kilometer ground). Hm, this is not that impossible after all :) you lose like 17V on 1 km of cable.

However if you have an arduino at every 100 meter, that means 120 Arduino, a solid 5.4A current draw. Maximum allowed current per conductor is 0.577A on a cat5 cable, so this won't work on 5V.

POE can make this a little easier, as it runs at up to 48V. By increasing the voltage, it is possible to use thinner wires, since less current at higher voltage carries the same power. PoE can wire 60W of power over 100 meters (with serious losses due to the thin copper wires in the Cat5e cable). So I would say, although the idea is insane (no offense :)) but actually it is possible to make it working.

However you can't do I2C on such a long cable. You have to go for at least RS485, and use it at a very low speed, say, 300 BPS if you want to have 12km.

Is there a chance to learn the problem you're trying to solve? There could have been much better solutions than 12km of wire. That is a serious cost in copper, not to mention the cost of a good PoE adapters. For a 12km long wire, you have to have very serious overvoltage protection, too. Probably a radio link and a battery-operated device would be a better choice, no?

Comment: Hi Gee Bee. Your explanation is solid. Thank you so much, What I am trying to achieve is having beacons in a mine to triangulate the positions of miners. Hench the 12km. No im still early in my research for this and I dont know if the mines would be able to provide power points ever so much meters hence I wanted to do the PoE route. As well I want to go solid cabling and not radio link as I think it might be a more stable and reliable solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, a mine is not a great place for ISM band radio communication. How do you plan to identify the position of the miners, btw?
A classic solution is as follows: use about 30-40VAC. Afaik up to 48V DC can be safely used in any mine without restrictions, but you need to check this. I prefer AC here, in order to avoid corrosion on the wire contact due to humidity which you may have there. Use a pair of 1.5mm2 (thats like AWG15) wire gauge to minimize power loss. (This is just from the sleeve, for exact calculation we need to know the total consumption of each Arduino.)

Comment: Use a pair of twisted pair wire for communication. An RS485 would do well, but instead of having the whole thing as one huge 12km long bus, I suggest to separate this at each arduino. So each Arduino would work as a "repeater" and would have an uplink (of 100m) and a downlink (of a 100m) to the next Arduinos. Don't forget to terminate these links at both end with a 120 ohm resistor. This can make a solid communication even at megabits of speed, and one short on the bus will not make the whole bus useless. Also it helps you later on to detect wiring breaks on the bus-it is a **mine** after all

Comment: Now, this will cost you a lot of wiring, since power and communication needs different wires. You may go for power wire communication - but I'd avoid of doing that in such a harsh environment. On the other hand, if you can improve your Arduino design, there is a lot of possible savings. For example, instead of using an off the shelf Arduino board, roll your own hardware, with a step-down regulator (only 10% power loss, not more than 300% with the built-in LDO), and use proper power savings mode. It is possible to reduce the power draw to around 1-2mA at 5V.

Comment: (If you want to use LEDs, instead of just using any off the shelf led and run it at 20mA, use a high power led which produces decent light at 0.5mA.) Then, you can go for CAT5E. There are four wire pairs. Use one pair for communication, and you have 6 wires left. Connect it so that 3 wires all carry power, another 3 wires all carry ground. This makes the wires "thicker" i.e. less resistance.

Comment: So: master node - around 36VAC goes via 3+3 wires, and RS485 goes over 2 wires (this all in one CAT5E cable) to the first Arduino node.
Each arduino node will have its own power converter: a simple rectifier, capacitor, and a step-down converter to make 5V local power for the Arduinos. It means that about 20V voltage drop can be tolerated with no harm :). Each arduino runs on low power - not the off the shelf solution. Each arduino has two RS485 transceiver, e.g. LTC485, one for the upstream and one for the downstream link.

Comment: Don't foreget the line termination resistors on the LTC485, and don't forget to add surge protection. On the power line inputs of each Arduino box, use a bidirectional transient suppressor of say, 50V (keep it over the normal voltage, but below the maximum input voltage of the stepdown). You may also add a varistor (MOV) as a secondary protection on the power lines. The data lines needs series resistors of like 68ohm, and fast zeners or other bidirectional suppressor of 6.8V.

Comment: Gee Bee. You honestly seem to know a lot with regards to this (much more then I do!) I am from South Africa Would it be possible if we could email each other, It would really be nice to pick your brain with regards to this. armandhansen(at)gmail(dot)com